# Get subset of dataframe directly from list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

I am tying to the subset of a dataframe directly from the list. Example below:

2 Data Frames

```
         d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3),y2=c(4,5,6),y3=c(7,8,9))
         d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1),y2=c(6,5,4),y3=c(9,8,7))
```

List:

```
          my.list <- list(d1, d2)
```

I would like to call a subset of a dataframe directly from the list

```
         my.list[1][,1:2]
        Error in my.list[1][, 1:2] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

My desired result is the below but I would like to call it directly from the list.

```
      d2[,1:2]

        y1 y2
      1  3  6
      2  2  5
      3  1  4
```

Thank you

Comment: `my.list[[1]][,1:2]`?

Comment: Works! Thank you!